# ¿Como puedo verificar unos datos que se encuentran dentro de una lista con condicionales?

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente inconveniente a la hora de verificar unos datos dentro de una lista, me arroja el siguiente error:

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Esta es la linea de codigo:

```
     DisparoUsuarioX = int(input("Dispareee, ingrese coordenada en x: "))
     DisparoUsuarioY = int(input("Dispareee, ingrese coordenada en y: "))
            **if [DisparoUsuarioX,DisparoUsuarioY] not in DisparosUsuario and [DisparoUsuarioX,DisparoUsuarioY] in BarcosBot:**
                        DisparosUsuario.append([ DisparoUsuarioX ,DisparoUsuarioY])
```

Alguno sabe a que se debe y como puedo solucionarlo?
Estoy atento.

Comment: ¿Qué contienen las variables `DisparosUsuario` y `BarcosBot`?

Comment: Se trata del juego batalla naval, Disparos Usuarios es una lista, en esta almaceno DisparioUsuarioX y DisparoUsuarioY. BarcosBot es una lista donde guardo las posiciones de los barcos de la computadora. Te paso mejor todo el codigo?

Comment: No pongas todo el código, solo debes poner lo necesario para replicar el problema. Puedes leer [ask].

Comment: Tu código no debería de dar error siempre y cuando los datos sean correctos. El error se produce por que ya sea `DisparosUsuario` o `BarcosBot` es un entero y no una lista.

Comment: Epa Christian, muchas gracias pero las variables las tengo como listas, acaso hay restriccion para manejarlas?

Comment: Nop, no hay restricciones. Solo imprime las variables antes del `if` y verifica sus valores.